# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'session') at LogoutSession NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have this router.delete in the Nodejs server that make the logout so the req.session enters full and then gets destroyed successfully the problem is when I use the res.send() to send the session or a message it doesn't work:

```
router.delete('/logout', async(req,res) => {
    console.log(req.session)
    req.session.destroy()
    res.send({ session: req.session });
    console.log(req.session)
    res.end()
});
```

I try to display the data that comes from that router on the react frontend like this and it tells me the error that is written in the title:

```
  const LogoutSession = async(e) =>{
      e.preventDefault();
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/logout`, {
            method:"DELETE",
        })
      console.log(response.data.session)     
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I used the method .json to send data to the frontend this way:

```
router.delete('/logout', async(req,res) => {
    try {
        console.log(sess)
        sess = null
        console.log(sess)
        res.status(200).json({code: 200, message: 'loggedout', session1: 
        sess})
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    res.end()

});
```

And then I used it like this in the frontend:

```
const LogoutSession = async(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/logout`, {
            method:"DELETE",
        })
    const data = await response.json();
    if(data.session1 === null){
        history.push('/')
    }
}
```